# how to insert an HTML after a span text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a span inside a div as follows.

```
<div class="class a" align="Right">
    &nbsp;
    <span id="Last_Name">Last Name</span>
    Text outside Span
</div>
```

I would like insert another span after "Text outside Span".

When I try $("#Last_Name").after(HtmlText); , the html is inserted before "Text outside span"

Comment: append - insert at end of, prepend - insert at start of -- after is well, after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.append("HTML OR Text")` to append text in element, which always appends Text or HTML at last, before ending of that particular element.

```js
$(".class.a").append("<span class='newSpan'>Another Span at before ending of element.</span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class a" align="Right">
    &nbsp;
    <span id="Last_Name">Last Name</span>
    Text outside Span
</div>
```

Comment: @premkris, Glad that it helped you, if you have any doubts feel free to ask. Also if you are satisfied with answer request you to accept the answer.